# Suggest the appropriate method of managing beans in Richfaces

Tags: jsf, scope, richfaces, managed-bean

The scenario is like this. I have a rich:tabPanel with about 5 tabs. On first tab there is a rich:datatable. When I click on first column's element (a4j:commandLink), I get another rich:datatable. When I click on first column's element (a4j:commandLink) of this table, I change the tab where I have another rich:datatable and the same thing follows as above. The constraints from previous tab is used to get elements for the current one. If I click on the tab directly I get all elements related to that tab. Each rich:datatable refers to different tables. Each table is interrelated. Each tab refers to a single managed bean. I am using hibernate in backend.

The problem starts now. I dont want the managed beans to be session or application based since there are many variables to store. If I give request scope, the following thing happens. The first table in the tab renders perfectly, however when I click on the first column, the second table doesn't use all constraints since the scope is request, for example actionlistener. What am I supposed to do ?

One thing I can do is define one managed bean for each table. Or forcefully use session scope. Or is there any other way? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already on JSF 2.0, use view scope. It's a scope which lives as long as you're interacting with the same page (independently of the browser tab/session!).

If you're still on JSF 1.x, use request scope with an [`<a4j:keepAlive beanName="#{bean}" />`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_keepAlive.html) declared in the view. It behaves like the JSF 2.0 view scope.

Comment: In view scope, is the bean maintained if I change tab in tabpanel ? As I mentioned each tab is a managed bean. So what happens when I change tab, since when I change the tab the view is changed ? TabPanel switch type is client.

Comment: Reference those beans in the view scoped one.

Comment: Thanks but thats not what I meant. If I give a managed bean view scope, each tab referencing a bean. When I change the tab in tabpanel are parameters maintained or is the scope for everything under <f:view> tag ?

Comment: That's not what I meant. Use one and same bean for all tabs. You can make each tab bean a property of this one and same bean.

Comment: Thanks. Rep++ :) One last thing, is a4j:keepalive working principle same as Icefaces' extended request scope ?

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I have no utter idea about IceFaces since I don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Richfaces 3.0.0 or above you can annotate your bean with `@KeepAlive`
or use the tag `<a4j:keepAlive beanName="#{bean}" />` instead.
This is an equivalent to the view scope in JSF 2.0.